# Paypal recurring payment change account and decline

Tags: paypal

My customer is using recurring payment. I have two problem to resolve:

Case 1 : My a customer have some recurring bill. This want change these recurring bill to other paypal account. Is there paypal api to support to delete recurring bills in current account and renew thes bills to new account.

Case 2 : If due to payment,customer's paypal account is not enough money, my system will lock some customer's function. I want paypal call my system 's function to handle this. Is there a way to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  You can use [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/) to cancel/suspend the profile on the existing account.  You'll need to have the user go through the process of creating the new profile on the new account, but this can be done via the use of [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/).

If you happen to be working with PHP my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make these calls very simple for you.

2)  You'll want to utilize [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to automate the management of the profiles.  PayPal will POST transaction data in real-time to a listener script that you have setup on your web server.  This script can receive that data and then update your database, send out email notifications, hit 3rd party services, or whatever you want to do from within it.

PayPal will send an IPN when a profile is created, updated, suspended, canceled, as well as when payments are completed, failed, skipped, etc.